How to assign > and < signs after finding the roots of a quadratic inequality?

In the reference question, we find the roots of the equation to be $-9$ and $-1$. When we set the quadratic equation to be $> 0$. The values received are $k < -9$ and $k > -1$. Shouldn't this be $-9 < k < -1$ instead?

first, please do not use images of questions, rather type them out using MathJax. second, have you tried simply calculating what happens to $\Delta$ when you insert values of $k$ so that $-9<k-1$?

There are two (at least) ways to approach this: numerically or graphically.
Numerically, $a\times b>0$ if $a,b>0$ or $a,b<0$.
So for $(k+1)(k+9)>0$ we require either both $k+9>0,k+1>0$ or $k+9<0,k+1<0$
And both must be true so it is the intersection of these intervals.
Hence the numerical solution is $k>-1$ or $k<-9$.
Graphically, imagine the graph of $y=(x+1)(x+9)$ for a moment. It is a positive parabola with zeroes at $x=-9$ and $x=-1$, so it is below the $x$-axis for $-9<x<-1$ and above for $x<-9$ and $x>-1$.
Replacing $x$ with $k$ gives the required solution (remembering to avoid $k=0$ because that makes the original function linear).

Just imagine a line that goes in two directions from zero and everything will always be clear
look, there are several good ways to determine + or -
substitute the value in from this interval in equation, the answer is positive means plus +, negative means minus -, when you equate to zero, you essentially find a place after which the value changes, if it says in simple terms, this is a certain point after which the value changes its behavior
Another way look at the coefficients k in your case, they are + and +, that is, + * + = +, so we start with a plus and alternate them every interval
i mean if you have something like (3-x)(4-x)/(3+x)(4-x)
we will imagine - * - / + * - So +/- = - so we start with -
obviously, in order for there to be roots, the discriminant must be positive, so we set the condition that the equation must be greater than zero, that is, we must choose positive sections
< 0 or > 0 means negative or positive numbers
and no, everything is correct here. Your equation just takes positive values in these intervals.
I hope it helped somehow

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
